# Running unit tests with pytest on functions

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

I am trying to run a unit test on a set of functions. The functions return multiple pandas dataframes.

How would I approach asserting equality between multiple dataframes using pytest?

Appreciate your help!

```
@pytest.fixture
def function_to_test():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'random': ['1'],'columns': ['One']})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'random': ['1'],'columns': ['One']})
    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'random': ['1'],'columns': ['One']})
    return df1, df2, df3


@pytest.fixture
def function_to_equal():
    df1e = pd.DataFrame({'random': ['1'],'columns': ['One']})
    df2e = pd.DataFrame({'random': ['1'],'columns': ['One']})
    df3e = pd.DataFrame({'random': ['1'],'columns': ['One']})
    return df1e, df2e, df3e


def unit_test_df-df3_function():
    #assert....?
```

Comment: See [`assert_frame_equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html)

Comment: Thanks root. Is there an efficient way of testing many data frames? For example I need to test input/output of many transformations. Seems tedious to create a data frame at each stage. Thanks!